# Why won't my form resize when clicked programmatically but it will when actually clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to make a .NET application that allows dwell timing clicks. This part has been implemented and works generally the way you'd expect.

This is the timer controlling dwell timing in my custom control:

```
private void dwellTimeEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    gr.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(127,128,128,128)), new Rectangle(0, this.Height - heightCounter, this.Width, this.Height / elapseDivide));

    if (heightCounter > this.Height * 12 / 10)
    {
        //this.ALSButton_Click(sender, e); // calls the click event programmatically rather than through an actual click
        this.OnClick(e);

    }
    else
    {
        heightCounter += this.Height / elapseDivide;
    }
}
```

This is the main GUI form calling the click event of the custom control above:

```
private void setBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Debug"); //make sure this method is being called
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;//this doesn't work with dwell timing and I don't know why
    /*this.Invalidate();
    this.Update();
    this.Refresh();
    Application.DoEvents();*/
}
```

I showed there in the comments all of the different things I tried. The messagebox appears either clicking or through waiting for the timer to expire but the form won't maximize unless I actually click it (rather than letting the timer run up). I am really confused as to why this is the case.

The other weird thing is, whenever I try to debug it using breakpoints, it works as I would anticipate; the dwell timing causes the form to maximize. This lead me to believe that maybe the GUI wasn't refreshing so I tried all the different commands above (Invalidate, refresh, etc) and none of them had an effect.

Comment: Use `Button.PerformClick()`

Comment: Do you mean replace the onClick call in the control? The control isn't a button but that's easily changed. I made it inherit the button and call the performclick method but it returned an invalid operation exception

Comment: OnClick() or Button.PerformClick() only runs *your* event handler.  It doesn't run all the other code inside the operating system that also processes the mouse click.  Activated by DefWndProc().  Which starts a modal loop to let the user resize the window with the mouse. None of that is .NET code.  There's just no point in doing it this way, you can simply set the Size property to achieve the exact same effect.

Comment: Graphic objects are short lived objects.  You are asking for trouble by storing that `gr` variable.  Get rid of it and always use the graphic object supplied by a paint event.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using System.Windows.Forms.Timer rather than System.Timers.Timer